# Need to bifurcate the client amounts committee wise

Tags: excel

[image]

need to bifurcate the client amount in committee wise.

Answer (score 0):

Excel Array(CSE) formula

```
=IF(D3:F3<>"",B3/COUNTA(D3:F3),0)
```

Copy the formula, Select I3 to K3, press f2, paste the formula, press Control+Shift+Enter (CSE). Note the curly braces after so entering the formula.

Select I3 to K3, copy and paste in I4, I5 and I6

[image]